# Indices in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, indices

I have the following 2 indices in mongo

> {a,b,c,d} (composite) (called rawIndex1)
>
> {c} (called time-gmt_1)

In one machine with a certain amount of data, a given query uses the first one

In a second machine with a lot more data, the same query uses the second one.

Is this expected behavior?

The only thing I can think is that in the second machine (with a lot of data), where the size of the first index is twice the size of the second, mongo prefers the second index because it cant keep the first one in RAM.

I checked that in the first machine the sizes of the indices are inverse to what happens in the second machine.

The output of explain("verbose") is

> {
>                            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor time-gmt_1",
>
> ```
>                      "isMultiKey" : false,
>
>                      "n" : 0,
>
>                      "nscannedObjects" : 6,
>
>                      "nscanned" : 7,
>
>                      "scanAndOrder" : false,
>
>                      "indexOnly" : false,
>
>                      "nChunkSkips" : 0,
>
>                      "indexBounds" : {
>
>                              "c" : [
>
>                                      [
>
>                                              ISODate("2014-12-31T00:00:00Z"),
>
>                                              ISODate("2015-01-07T23:59:59Z")
>
>                                      ]
>
>                              ]
>
>                      }
>               },
> ```
>
> "cursor" : "BtreeCursor rawIndex1",
>
> ```
>                      "isMultiKey" : false,
>
>                      "n" : 6,
>
>                      "nscannedObjects" : 6,
>
>                      "nscanned" : 6,
>
>                      "scanAndOrder" : false,
>
>                      "indexOnly" : false,
>
>                      "nChunkSkips" : 0,
>
>                      "indexBounds" : {
>
>                       "a" : [
>
>                                      [
>
>                                              "an",
>
>                                              "an"
>
>                                      ]
>
>                              ],
>
>                              "b" : [
>
>                                      [
>                                              "bn",
>
>                                              "bn"
>
>                                      ]
>
>                              ],
>
>                              "c" : [
>
>                                      [
>
>                                              ISODate("2014-12-31T00:00:00Z"),
>
>                                              ISODate("2015-01-07T23:59:59Z")
>
>                                      ]
>
>                              ],
>
>                              "d" : [
>
>                                      [
>
>                                              "d1",
>
>                                              "d1"
>
>                                      ],
>
>                                       [
>
>                                              "d2",
>
>                                              "d2"
>
>                                      ],
>
>                                      [
>
>                                              "d3",
>
>                                              "d3"
>
>                                      ]
>
>                                   ]
>
>                            }
> ```
>
> "cursor" : "BtreeCursor time-gmt_1",
>
> ```
>     "isMultiKey" : false,
>
>     "n" : 6,
>
>     "nscannedObjects" : 6,
>
>     "nscanned" : 19755316,
>
>     "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 26,
>
>     "nscannedAllPlans" : 19755339,
>
>     "scanAndOrder" : false,
>
>     "indexOnly" : false,
>
>     "nYields" : 4,
>
>     "nChunkSkips" : 0,
>
>     "millis" : 847364,
> ```

Comment: Run your query with `db.collectionName.find(query).explain(true)` for a verbose output of the explain plan. You are not talking about "machines", but "datasets" which are completely different. The "explain" output tells you what the "query optimizer" is doing, and all of the scenarios it considered. It chose the "optimal" one where one index was considered better. Also see [`.hint()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/) to force things and see the degradation in performance, or possibly better, but we hope not.

Comment: I ran the explain command to find which index is using. I also ran in the second dataset/machine the hint with the first index and mongo returns much much much faster than the second that mongo is using by default. So am confused here. Perhaps I need to tell it to re-evaluate the query plans?

Comment: Then maybe so. Like I said, "We would hope not". But it is not the first time an "optimizer" gets it wrong. Been "hinting" SQL RDBMS for many years.

Comment: But it is not even close. Using the second index takes 10 mins while using the first takes 1 sec

Comment: Can you post the explain output? I would not use run time as a gauge, especially when dealing with 2 different sized data sets.

Comment: Yes I added it to the post above

Comment: The explains look abridged. There should be more fields. Also, what are the queries that produce these explains? I see different values for `n`, which implies different queries or different data. Can you clarify what the query is and what machine it's run on for each explain?